# Naming files automatically in php

Tags: php, file, auto-increment

I was looking for a way to name my files in numbers,e.g 1.text,2.text...

But this should be done automatically. When saving A new file, the program should take the maximum number among the files in the directory, and name the new folder that number plus one.

A hint given is that we can use auto increment. How can we do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fileDir = 'your_file_dir';
$fileIterator = new FilesystemIterator($fileDir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$numberOfFiles = iterator_count($fileIterator)+1; // Count the number of files in $fileDir
$f = fopen("{$fileDir}/{$numberOfFiles}.txt", 'w');
fclose($f);
```